# sequence indexing notation

Tags: indexing, sequence

I am trying to typeset a sequence s with index.
Trying to use
`$s_{N+1}$`
looks weird since the `N` is too large in comparison to `s`.
So I did double lower index which looks better but the plus sign spacing looks still off
`$s_{_{N+1}}$`.
Using
`$s_{_{N\text{+}1}}$`
seems to do the trick but its a lot of tex for a simple expression.

Same problem with
`$\mathbb{R}^{2N}$`
which look odd in my opinion. The following looks better:
`$\mathbb{R}^{^{2N}}$`.

Is there a best-practice or common convention how to typeset these expressions in general?

Comment: I'd use the natural form but if you want to make it smaller, `s_{\scriptscriptstyle N+1}` not a double subscript and definitely not `\text` (which takes the + from the surrounding text fornt not math at all)

Comment: thank you. And what about the upper indices? Also, are they typeset upright or slanted?

Comment: You could use an old style long s :o)

Comment: The same, don't use `^{^`  typeset N in a superscript in the same style that you would use when refering to the same concept on the main baseline so N is normally italic but if you use `\mathrm{N}` to denote something use the same if it occurs in a superscript.

Comment: also of course if you have the choice, use n not N then the problem goes away